# What is or was modernity, the sociological phenomena?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-history, modernism, modernity

What is or was modernity, the sociological phenomena?

I'm asking cos I want to know what aestrhetic modernism was, and would like to build up my understanding from the ground up.

What book length (or especially good shorter) studies talks about the phenomena in the most insightful way?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modernity

Comment: @JohnAm most insightful reference ??

Comment: What do you feel like might be missing or confusing in the resources you've found already?

Comment: About the sociological environment I have found a great resource the book by Mario De Micheli "the Avant-garde movements of the 20th century". The author is Italian and I'm not sure if there is an English translation. I have read the Greek translation when i was studying history of art. http://www.academia.edu/12935227/Mario_De_Michelli_-_Las_vanguardias_art%C3%ADsticas_del_siglo_XX

Comment: Probably [Anthony Giddens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Giddens)'s works can be a good starting-points; e.g. [The Consequences of Modernity](https://books.google.it/books?id=SVmkJEwWGwAC&printsec=frontcover) (1990).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA that looks like a good read, i will add it to the bucket list at least JohnAm thanks